# How to put buttons and strings together into a javafxml scrollpane?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I am trying to put a button and a string next to each other into a scrollpane for every object in an ArrayList. Which means i need to append this to the scrollpane multiple times.

```
@FXML
     private ScrollPane scrollElem; 


@FXML

     private void getElements(MouseEvent event){

            customer obj = writeCustomerToFile.getObject();
            ArrayList<customer> array = obj.putCustomersInArray();

            Label scrollContent = new Label();
            scrollContent.setText("");
            Button button = new Button(); 
            scrollElem.setContent(scrollContent,button); 
     }

//I am looking for something similar code shown above
```

Comment: Not sure what the desired result is, but maybe you'd be better off using a `ListView` or a `TableView`.

Comment: You cannot set multiple content nodes at the same time. It's possible to add a layout as content and add multiple children to this layout though...